# Does someone know other examples of $K$-semigroups?

Tags: abstract-algebra, semigroups

In our work on projective representations we need use the following object:

Let  $K$ be a field. By a $K$-*semigroup*  we mean a semigroup $S$ with $0$ and a map $K \times S \to S$ such that
$\alpha (\beta x) = (\alpha \beta )x,$ $\alpha (xy) = (\alpha x ) y = x (\alpha y),$ $1_K x =x$ for any
$\alpha , \beta \in K, x,y \in S$ and the zero of $K$ multiplied by any
element of $S$ is $0 \in S.$

Of course  K-algebras considered as multiplicative semigroups are K-semigroups. 
I wonder if someone met other K-semigroups in his algebraic practice.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why do you assume that $K$ is a field? As for the definition, it could be any semigroup with $0$. What you call a $K$-semigroup is an action of $K$ on a semigroup with $0$ in the general sense of actions in monoidal categories.

For fixed $K$, the $K$-semigroups constitute a variety in the sense of universal algebra. Hence there are *lots* of constructions, for example quotients by congruence relations, generated substructures, free structures, limits, colimits. This gives lots of specific examples of $K$-semigroups.

For example, the free $K$-semigroup generated by an object $x$ consists of $0$ and elements of the form $(\alpha_1 \cdot x^{k_1}) \cdot \dotsc \cdot (\alpha_n \cdot x^{k_n})$, where $\alpha_i \in K \setminus \{0,1\}$ and $k_i \geq 1$.